# Cannot set org.hibernate.cfg.DefaultComponentSafeNamingStrategy in Jboss AS7 with hibernate 3.6 (ClassCastException)

Tags: java, hibernate, jboss, seam

I am in the middle of migrating our Seam 2.2.2/JPA1/JEE5/glassfish v2 application to Seam 2.3/JPA2/Hibernate 3.6/JEE6/Jboss AS7. So far I was making progress but now I am stuck at setting the `hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy` setting in persistence.xml to `org.hibernate.cfg.DefaultComponentSafeNamingStrategy`:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.cfg.DefaultComponentSafeNamingStrategy cannot be cast to   org.hibernate.cfg.NamingStrategy
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:1086) [hibernate3.jar:3.6.10.Final]
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:290) [hibernate3.jar:3.6.10.Final]
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:372) [hibernate3.jar:3.6.10.Final]
... 74 more
```

As you can see, hibernate3.jar:3.6.10.Final is loaded as required but somehow the class loader has some issues or interference with another version.

Hibernate 4 is excluded in the jboss-deployment-structure.xml:

```
    <exclusions>
        <module name="org.hibernate" slot="main"/>
        <module name="org.hibernate.envers" slot="main"/>
        <module name="org.hibernate.validator" slot="main"/>
    </exclusions>
```

There is no hibernate related jar packaged with the application war. It is loaded as AS7 module:

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.0" name="org.hibernate" slot="3">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="hibernate-validator-4.1.0.Final.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="hibernate3.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate" slot="3"/>
        <module name="asm.asm"/>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="javax.persistence.api"/>
        <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
        <module name="javax.validation.api"/>
        <module name="org.antlr"></module>
        <module name="org.javassist"/>
        <module name="org.slf4j"/>
        <module name="org.apache.log4j"/>
        <module name="org.apache.commons.collections"></module>
        <module name="org.dom4j"></module>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

And referenced via `<property name="jboss.as.jpa.providerModule" value="org.hibernate:3"/>` in peristence.xml.

When I remove the naming strategy setting, the application continues to load but crashes a bit later because of naming conflicts which are normally solved by the safe naming strategy.

Comment: Note: Setting the naming strategy to ``org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy`` works (but also causes naming errors)...

Comment: I also just noticed AS7 still loading Hibernate 4 in addition to the already loaded 3.6:
  `14:24:20,811 INFO  [org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version] (MSC service thread 1-5) HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.1.Final}
  14:24:20,817 INFO  [org.hibernate.Version] (MSC service thread 1-5) HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.0.1.Final}`